# .htaccess rules in folder are not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder with name `products` and i want to rewrite the with htaccess (htaccess is placed in folder)

the code i have used is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /products/

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?product=$1&brand=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Now what i am trying to achieve is 
i want to convert

```
abc.com/products/index.php?product=toshiba-laptop&brand=toshiba&page=3
```

to

```
abc.com/products/toshiba-laptop/toshiba/3
```

Comment: Have you set `AllowOverride all` in your vhost?

Comment: yes allowoverride is set to all

Comment: @opncart `([0-9]+)` is supposed to match `toshiba`?

Comment: that was a mistake corrected

Comment: you have access to the server config?

Comment: @ManZzup yes i have access to VPS

Answer (score 0):

Solve myself thanks code is use is

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([a-z-]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&brand=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([a-z-]+)/(.*)/$ index.php?cat=$1&brand=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&brand=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```